# How to set a blob column in the where clause using spark-connector-api?

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to figure out how to set a blob column under where clause. any idea?

For example if I put the following query in cqlsh it works

```
select * from hello where id=0xc1c1795a0b;
```

//id is a blob column in cassandra

I tried the following

```
JavaRDD<CassandraRow> cassandraRowsRDD = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("test", "hello")
.select("range" )
.where("id=?", "0xc1c1795a0b");
```

This gave me a type converter exception

and I tried this

```
JavaRDD<CassandraRow> cassandraRowsRDD = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("test", "hello")
.select("range" )
.where("id=?", "0xc1c1795a0b".getBytes());
```

This gave me no error however it returned no results. The query in my cqlsh did return bunch of results. so I am not sure to set a blob in the where clause. I am using Java. any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this.

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.utils.Bytes;

JavaRDD<CassandraRow> cassandraRowsRDD = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("test", "hello")
.select("range" )
.where("id=?",Bytes.getArray(Bytes.fromHexString("0xc1c1795a0b")));
```

Comment: Thanks! I have another problem that has been super hard to trace. can you please look into this one?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953245/how-to-fix-java-lang-classcastexception-cannot-assign-instance-of-scala-collect